# How do I remove Nikkud (vowel marks) from a Word 2016 document?

Tags: formatting, language, microsoft-word

I am working on a commentary on Ethics of the Fathers and I want readers to be able to read sources I'm quoting in their original Hebrew. I am getting most of my sources from [sefaria.org](http://sefaria.org) and unfortunately many of the sources have Nekudos (vowel marks) while most of them don't. For consistency and professionalism I want all the sources to not contain Nekudos.

For example [this line:](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.1.1?lang=bi&with=Bartenura&lang2=he) מֹשֶׁה קִבֵּל תּוֹרָה מִסִּינַי. אוֹמֵר אֲנִי, לְפִי שֶׁמַּסֶּכֶת זוֹ should be משה קבל תורה מסיני. אומר אני שמסכת זו. I expect to need to do this hundreds of times so I need something fast. Somebody once made me a document with Macros to do this but it isn't working on Word 2016. Does anyone else have an efficient way to do it? Thank you so much.

Comment: Can someone please add Hebrew as a tag? I can't do it yet. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try notepad++?

Comment: Added a few tags. Does that help?  You may want to try looking in the Hebrew community or the SuperUser community of stack Exchange. I wish I could find a direct link to either community, but I did quickly come across this question. Not sure if it is relevant. https://superuser.com/questions/769204/hebrew-nikkud-on-ms-word

Comment: @BugFolk I've changed the tags to include [microsoft-word] and [formatting]. Hebrew is not viable as a tag, because while the question is about vowel marks on Hebrew, it could easily apply to any language. Plus 'Hebrew' is not a tag, and it's good practice to avoid creating tags whenever possible. Similarly, the tags [software] and [language] did not fit the question, which was not asking about a language, nor specifically about software. The OP was asking about MS Word specifically, so that's a far better tag than 'software'.

Comment: Okay. Good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick Google search on `hebrew remove nikkud` gave an answer.

On [Github](https://gist.github.com/yakovsh/345a71d841871cc3d375) there's a JavaScript with a live preview [code](https://jsfiddle.net/js0ge7gn/3/). If it's little text you could use the JavaScript either online or download and use it on your pc (save as `.js`).

The Hebrew charcodes are all between 1425 and 1479 and the nikkud are between 0591 and 05C7.

Python implementation (tested):

```
import unicodedata
# nikkud-test.txt is the file you save your text in.
f= open('nikkud-test.txt','r', encoding='utf-8') 
content = f.read()
normalized=unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', content)
no_nikkud=''.join([c for c in normalized if not unicodedata.combining(c)])
no_nikkud
f.close()
f = open('no-nikkud-test.txt','w',encoding='utf-8')
fw = f.write(no_nikkud)
f.close()
```

This works very fast.

UPDATED:
How to use this script?

1. Download *Python 3.x.x* from the [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
2. Save your nikkud text to `nikkud-test.txt` in whatever directory
3. From the start menu start your `cmd` shell/command prompt/terminal.
4. Move to directory where you saved your file by typing `cd` followed by the directory
5. type `python` or open an `iPython` console.
6. copy + paste script
7. `no-nikkud-test.txt` will show up in the same directory

---

UPDATE without Terminal (Tested with Python 3.5 IDLE and iPython)

1. Download *Python 3.5* or higher from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
2. Save your niqqud text to `niqqud.txt` in your Documents folder. (Windows / Mac)
3. Open IDLE from the Start Menu. (Alternatively, use [iPython](https://ipython.org/install.html))

Copy and paste the function below:

```
def hasar_niqqud(source="niqqud.txt"):
    """This function removes niqqud vowel diacretics from Hebrew.
    @param source: The source filename with .txt extension."""
    import os, unicodedata
    path  = os.path.expanduser('~/Documents/'+str(source))
    f= open(path,'r', encoding='utf-8')
    content = f.read()
    normalized=unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', content)
    no_niqqud=''.join([c for c in normalized if not unicodedata.combining(c)])
    f.close()
    path  = os.path.expanduser('~/Documents/'+str(source)[:-4]+"-removed.txt")
    f = open(path,'w',encoding='utf-8')
    f.write(no_niqqud)
    f.close()
```

Then run the function with this code:

```
hasar_niqqud()
```

That's it! You can find the output in the Documents folder `niqqud-removed.txt`

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm not familiar with coding. How do I use this?

Comment: For those of us who are technically challenged, could you explain where to download Python3 and how to start a `cmd` shell?

Comment: Updated. The command prompt is also called terminal on other systems. It is not as hard as it seems. It's just a little overwhelming at first.

Comment: I don't know. I spent a while trying to follow these instructions and I keep getting error codes. I really know nothing about using these kinds of programs.

Comment: Try installing iPython https://ipython.org/install.html It has a better interface than the terminal.

Comment: Added a simplified tutorial without the need for the terminal. I will remove the earlier tutorial if it is too complicated (?). I have to say I have learnt quite about Hebrew :)

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the exact same thing. Dug around and found ways to do it outside Word, but really wanted to do this without leaving Word. Did some more reading and discovered the key is to run a find and replace, searching for the vowel characters in the Hebrew Unicode block. I wanted to keep maqqef and sof pasuq, so I had to use three separate ranges (if you don't want those characters, you can simplify this to one search for the whole range 1425-1479). The results are below. If you select text and run the macro, it will only apply to the selection. If you don't have a selection, it will run to end of document.

```
Sub HebrewDevocalizer()
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "[" & ChrW(1425) & "-" & ChrW(1469) & "]"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchKashida = False
    .MatchDiacritics = False
    .MatchAlefHamza = False
    .MatchControl = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "[" & ChrW(1471) & "-" & ChrW(1474) & "]"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchKashida = False
    .MatchDiacritics = False
    .MatchAlefHamza = False
    .MatchControl = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "[" & ChrW(1476) & "-" & ChrW(1479) & "]"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchKashida = False
    .MatchDiacritics = False
    .MatchAlefHamza = False
    .MatchControl = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

In case your list is in Excel you could use this macro (based on the suggestion of Jonathan Potter). Select a range of cells, then execute the macro in VBEditor.

```
Sub HebrewDevocalizer()
Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1425 To 1469
        Selection.Replace What:=ChrW(i), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next i
    For i = 1471 To 1474
        Selection.Replace What:=ChrW(i), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False
    Next i
    For i = 1476 To 1479
        Selection.Replace What:=ChrW(i), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I looked for an App that would provide the nikud (vowels) to words I was using to create a glossary.  However, once I had the words in that form, I could no longer sort them (as we can tell from these questions).

However, the same App, https://nakdan.dicta.org.il/ also allows the user to select the "modern Hebrew" version, and if you click on לחץ כאן (click here) a little dialog box appears.  Click on the black box that basically takes you to another version to add vowels, it actually then wipes out whatever vowels you had there.

You may have to play around a bit with it to get the hang of it and/or do it in parts.

Then you can just copy and paste into your spreadsheet in a temporary column to use for sorting.  After final sorting, delete that column.

Give that a try for a work-around!

Regards,
Madeleine

Comment: Hi Madeleine, welcome to writing.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. This is a nice first answer, thanks for participating and happy writing!

Comment: Here's a webpage that removes nikud:
http://www.eshkol.net/Nikud/Default.aspx
הסרת ניקוד Hasarat Nikkud